# Facebook: My iFrame-based app working app doesn't open any more

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-iframe

I had a working application on Facebook that even made it to the App directory.
Now all of a sudden, when I hit the URL, it goes into an infinite kind of loop, and finally times-out with the message:

```
The connection has timed out

The server at apps.facebook.com is taking too long to respond.
```

The app is available at: http://apps.facebook.com/simple-wishes/?ref=canvas_bkmk_top&count=0

I have made no changes to the code since month, and it worked fine all along. Has FB made any changes that I am not aware of? Thanks in advance

Comment: see how the redirect is working using something like firebug

Comment: my app also got the same prob, it just reloads infinitely !

Comment: Try this one http://i.imgur.com/TOkJw.jpg

Comment: You know that I'm not going to add your application to test it for you right? Anyways, since the Permissions dialog appear then I assume it's working.

Comment: Thanks haha, will check & revert.
ifaour, yes sadly you will have to add to test. But the Permissions dialog is rendered by FB and not by custom code. So its not a sufficient condition to guarantee that the app is working.

Comment: I changed settings as suggested by haha, but it doesn't work! I have no clue why this is happening!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem. A couple of month ago my application was working fine and it was an iframe based app. But suddenly its behavior was same as you discussed.

If you are using new FB-APi then my suggestions are that please change your facebook-application settings from developer.

In advanced setting tab. 
OAuth 2.0 for Canvas = Enable
Upgrade to Requests 2.0:  = Enable.

hopefully it will resolve your problem

Comment: THanks for your reply Hassan. Both those options are enabled for my app, but that hasn't helped :(